# Subalgebras of singular matrices (less naive version)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ra.rings-and-algebras

Is it true that, for any subalgebra $\cal S$
of the algebra of linear operators in a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a field,
$$
\bigcap_{A\in\cal S}\ker A=\{0\}\hbox{ and }
\bigcup_{A\in\cal S}A(V)=V
\quad\hbox{implies that}
\quad\hbox{some $A\in\cal S$ is non-singular? } 
$$

(A more naive version of this question [was answered by Benjamin Steinberg](https://mathoverflow.net/a/397766/24165).)

Comment: My updated answer to your original question shows the answer is no.

Comment: Why? ${\cal S}V\ne V$.

Comment: Sorry you are right. No answering questions before coffee.

Comment: Consider the set of 4 x 4 matrices, whose lower left 3 x 3 block is zero.

Comment: I think to get this to work you want $SN^kV=N^kV$ for all k where N is the radical of S.

Comment: @Zero, why not 3x3 matrices with 2x2 zero block? Maybe, you wish to post an answer (to make the question ``officially closed'')? Thanks!

Comment: Notice in the 3x3 version of @Zero's answer if N is the radical, then NV consists of those vectors with last coordinate 0 and SNV consist of those vectors with the last two coordinates 0.

Comment: Benjamin, do you conjecture that ${\cal S}N^kV=N^kV$ for all $k$ is a necessary and sufficient condition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $S$ b be the set of 3 x 3 matrices whose lower left 2 x 2 block equals zero. Then $S$ is an algebra satisfying the conditions, but containing no invertible matrix.